# How can I "grep" recursively filtering the name of the files I want with wildcards?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, file-filter

When I want to perform a recursive grep search in the current directory, I usually do:

```
grep -ir "string" .
```

But that command searches inside all kinds of files, including binary files (pictures, audio, video, etc...) which results in a very slow search process.

If I do this, for example, it doesn't work:

```
grep -ir "string" *.php
```

It doesn't work because there are no PHP files inside the current directory, but inside some of the subdirectories in the current directory, and the subdirectories' names don't end with ".php" so grep doesn't look inside them.

So, how can I do a recursive search from the current directory but also specifying filename wildcards? (i.e: only search in files which end in a specific extension)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use `grep`'s `--include` option:

```
grep -ir "string" --include="*.php" .
```

Comment: Ok, it seems my version of grep was old, because it didn't have that option (no wonder why I couldn't figure out how to do this!). I got the message: "grep: unrecognized option `--include=*.php'". But I just upgraded to a newer one and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: I had to replace the period at the end and use:
`grep -ir "string" --include="*.php" *`

Comment: I thought period was just the end of the line! I did not use or need.

Comment: Is there a way to make `grep`'s `--include` option case-insensitive? So that the command would output both `*.php` and `*.PHP` files. `-i` seem to apply only to what is searched inside of the targeted filenames, and not to the filenames themselves.

Answer (score 17):

If you have a version of `grep` that lacks the `--include` option, you can use the following. These were both tested on a directory structure like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── a
├── b
│   └── foo2.php
├── c
│   └── d
│       └── e
│           └── f
│               └── g
│                   └── h
│                       └── foo.php
├── foo1.php
└── foo.php
```

Where all the `.php` files contain the string `string`.

1. Use `find`

   ```
   $ find . -name '*php' -exec grep -H string {} +
   ./b/foo2.php:string
   ./foo1.php:string
   ./c/d/e/f/g/h/foo.php:string
   ```

   #### Explanation

   This will find all `.php` files and then run `grep -H string` on each of them. With `find`'s `-exec` option, `{}` is replaced by each of the files found. The `-H` tells `grep` to print the file name as well as the matched line.
2. Assuming you have a new enough version of `bash`, use `globstar` :

   ```
   $ shopt -s globstar
   $ grep -H string  **/*php
   b/foo2.php:string
   c/d/e/f/g/h/foo.php:string
   foo1.php:string
   ```

   #### Explanation

   As explained in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

   > globstar
   >
   > If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories match.

   So, by running `shopt -s globstar` you are activating the feature and 
   Bash's `globstar` option which makes `**/*php` expand to all `.php` files in the current directory (`**` matches 0 or more directories, so `**/*php` matches `./foo.php` as well) which are then grepped for `string`.

Answer (score -2):

Use `*/*.php`

This makes grep search one level of  subdirectory

Comment: Something went wrong as asterisks and dots disappeared.

Comment: You can use backticks to format code and avoid ambiguity about the use of asterisks for emphasis in markdown formatting. P.S. note the question asks about "recursive search" in the final paragraph (not my downvote though).

Comment: Not a correct answer, because it's only good for one level deep directory structures, as you mention, but still good to know nonetheless ;). My upvote for that.